# How to "Copy but keep both files" with xcopy in batch

Tags: batch-file

first thread here, i need to know how to "Copy but keep both files" a directory i am copying on startup with a batch file.  This is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF    
color 1F    
cls    
:choice    
echo Do you want to backup saves?    
set /P c=[Y/N]?     
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :y    
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :somewhere_else    
goto :choice    
:y   
cls
title Making Backup of saves...    
XCOPY C:\Users\Jaydon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\VersionFiles\1.9\saves\*     
C:\Backupof1.9\ /i /s /r /y    
cls    
:done    
echo Done!    
set /P c=Press a key to exit.    
if /I "%c%" EQU "" goto :doneexit    
exit
:doneexit    
cls    
exit       
pause     
exit    
cls    
:somewhere_else    
cls    
echo You have chosen to exit!    
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 > nul    
exit    
cls
```

I need to copy all of the folders and files from:

```
"C:\Users\Jaydon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\VersionFiles\1.9\saves\*"
```

to

```
"C:\Backupof1.9\"
```

So far this just overrites it, which is fine. but it would be nice to have it create a new folder or add (1),2,3,4,5 and so on.

Any help appreciated, jjws600

Comment: Do you want to backup this entire folder and tree, to a different folder every time?  `"C:\Users\Jaydon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\VersionFiles\1.9\saves\*"`

Comment: I'd like to copy the saves folder to C:\Backupof1.9\ adding (1),(2) every time. so that i have backups of everytime i use the batch file.

Thanks, jjws600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should backup your saves to the location you requested, but using the date and time of when the backup was made - and it sorts correctly in a listing so the most recent folder is always at the bottom.

It assumes you have permissions to write to the root of the c: drive where the folder is.

```
@echo off
rem The four lines below will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec MS variables in XP Pro and higher.

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%" & set "MS=%dt:~15,3%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%" & set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%-%MS%"

echo datestamp: "%datestamp%"
echo timestamp: "%timestamp%"
echo fullstamp: "%fullstamp%"
if not defined fullstamp goto :EOF

set "datafolder=C:\Users\Jaydon\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\VersionFiles\1.9\saves"
set "backupfolder=C:\Backupof1.9\%fullstamp%"

set switches=/r:0 /w:0 /mir /ns /nc /ndl /np /njh /njs

robocopy %switches% "%datafolder%" "%backupfolder%"

pause
```